# I only want to return one artist from my spotify search

Tags: java, android, curl, get, spotify

Hello I only want to return one artist from my search but it seem to return more is it possible. Thank you. My search query is as follows:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track,artist&market=US" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

Comment: I just did this `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track,artist&market=US&limit=1`, does that work? All I did was add `limit=1`

Comment: Thanks user302975 that helped a little, but I seem too have returned the albums with this query https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=muse&offset=0&limit=20&type=album. Purely luck on my part. I used the spotify.searchAlbums() callback and extracted it from my second parameter i.e retrofit.client.Response response in the public void success() function

Comment: You did the right thing by removing `track` from the `type` parameter (having `type=album` will only return albums), but you should also apply `limit=1` to only get the first search result.